# Prevent pandas from converting datetime objects into pandas Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a very simple problem. I want to parse datetime strings as python datetime objects and store them in a pandas dataframe. However, I can't figure out how to prevent pandas from converting the datetime object into a pandas Timestamp. For example:

```
import dateutil
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

time = '2020-11-03T15:55:21'

no_pandas = dateutil.parser.parse(time)
print (type(no_pandas))

#Create a simple csv
convert = {'Time': lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x)}
csv = StringIO(f'Time\n{time}')
df = pd.read_csv(csv, parse_dates=False, converters=convert)

print (type(df.iloc[0]['Time']))
```

which prints:
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

Why is pandas overriding my preference for datetime objects and how can I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? If you need datetime functionality like access to attributes (like year, month etc.), you can use pandas datetime. If not, just leave the datetime as string and convert if needed.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason pandas seems to override the type to pd.Timestamp. You should make sure pandas will read the column as a Series of dtype="object". So you should do something like:

```py
df['Time'] = pd.Series(df['Time'].dt.to_pydatetime(), dtype="object")
```

Answer (score 1):

After you load into `pandas` add `to_pydatetime`

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.to_pydatetime()
```

Out

```
type(pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.to_pydatetime()[0])
Out[46]: datetime.datetime
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, still getting a pandas Timestamp

Comment: @Will.Evo I post the output from my end

Comment: Yeah for me its still a timestamp. If I run your out line of code, I get datetime, but if I run the first line of code, then every time I access the time from the dataframe, its still a pandas Timestamp

Comment: @Will.Evo that is why I mentioned , after you load the csv into pandas.~

Comment: Right, but I don't want to have to add .to_pydatetime every single time I pluck an entry out of the csv, I just want to have it formatted as a datetime object already.

Comment: @Will.Evo https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18305 seems like a common issue

Comment: This is an obvious idea/solution (similar to @BENY, I applied `.map(lambda t: t.to_pydatetime())`). But the format does not persist. For some reason, Pandas insistently coerces `datetime.datetime` objects into native Pandas timestamp objects. This is what OP is asking about.